# Ionic4 and angular8 module import as become main module

Tags: angular, ionic4

im using Ionic 4 with Angular 8, I have a few tabs and one of them import a pageModule for a chart that I include in the HTML. The problem is when I open this tab, it try to load de imported chart before the main page. I tried to change some imports but i cant get it to work, probably I dont get how thats work yet. I put some examples from my code.

This is the module that I import for chart:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [GraphDetailPage],
  exports: [GraphDetailPage]
})
export class GraphDetailPageModule {}
```

This is the module that contain the chart in the HTML:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    PipesModule,
    GraphDetailPageModule
  ],
  declarations: [GraphPage]
})
export class GraphPageModule {}
```

This two modules are imported in app.module.ts

Comment: Are you lazy loading these modules?

Comment: For what I understand, Im using lazy load, I change the configuration in app-routing.module.ts to NoPreloading, but its have no efect

Comment: If you have your routing setup correctly, there is no need to import the modules in the app module.  Try removing them from `app.module.ts`.

Comment: I removed them from the app.module.ts, but the problem persist

Comment: Hard to tell from the supplied code.  Might be helpful to create a stackblitz recreating the issue.